# How to add two values while splitting from boost library

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

This is my code where i am splitting a string using boost library.

```
std::vector<std::string> AllCommands;
std::string s="command1;command2;command3"
boost::split(AllCommands,s,boost::is_any_of(";"));
```

I want to perform the same operation on a struct where string txt will hold the text from string s and  int i will hold value 1.

```
struct vCmd
{
 std::string txt;
 int i;
};

std::vector<struct vCmd> AllCommands;
std::string s ("command1;command2;command3")
boost::split(AllCommands,s,boost::is_any_of(";"));  // Need to modify this line
```

Comment: Create a constructor for vCmd which accepts a std::string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you define your own Container struct to hold commands and use `boost::split` directly.

See it [**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/443a8f48429c8ef7)

- Declared `std::iterator` inside `AllCommands`

> ```
> typedef std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,
> std::string, ptrdiff_t, std::string*, std::string&>
> iterator;
> ```

- constructor accepting 2 iterators

> ```
> template<typename Iter> 
> AllCommands(Iter i1, Iter i2)
> ```

- and a swap function

> `void swap(AllCommands&) {}`

**Program:**

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef struct vCmd
{
    std::string txt;
    int i;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const vCmd&);
}vCmd;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const vCmd& cmd)
{   
    stream << " {txt=" << cmd.txt << ",i=" << cmd.i << "} ";
    return stream;
}

struct AllCommands
{ 
    typedef std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,
    std::string, ptrdiff_t, std::string*, std::string&>
    iterator;

    AllCommands() {}

    template<typename Iter> 
    AllCommands(Iter i1, Iter i2)
    {
        std::vector<vCmd> cmds;

        //Constrct a vector of vCmd objects
        std::for_each(i1, i2, [&cmds](std::string const& t) { 
            cmds.push_back({t, std::stoi(t.substr(t.find_last_not_of("0123456789") + 1))}); 
        });

        //Now print the vector
        std::copy(cmds.begin(), cmds.end(), std::ostream_iterator<vCmd>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    void swap(AllCommands&) {}
};

int main()
{
    AllCommands cmds;
    boost::split(cmds, "command1;command2;command3", boost::is_any_of(";"));
    boost::split(cmds, "command8;command7;command9", boost::is_any_of(";"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
 {txt=command1,i=1}   {txt=command2,i=2}   {txt=command3,i=3}  
 {txt=command8,i=8}   {txt=command7,i=7}   {txt=command9,i=9}
```